# INSERT statement runs correctly but throws a 'violation of PK contstraint' error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am inserting the first product in the `Products` table. My answer statement works correctly, but I get a violation of primary key constraint:

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object. The duplicate key value is [...].

The record inserts correctly, but it also inserts a "0" record above the record I inserted. Not sure what is going on.

I can't see where my insert statement is wrong, I based it on an insert statement from sqlservertutorial.net. I don't know what is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO products (code, P_Name, p_line, P_Collection, P_Colour,
                      P_Size, P_Price, active)
VALUES ('17881832980551', 'Austin Record', 'T-Shirt', 'Classic', 'Athletic Heather',
        'S', '39.50', 'Y');
```

The `Code` column in my `Products` table is the primary key.

The records is getting inserted correctly, as expected, but I also get an extra "0" record inserted, as well as the following error message:

> (2 rows affected)
>
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__Products__A25C5AA60C388384'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Products'. The duplicate key value is (17881832980551)

Comment: are there any triggers?

Comment: So to clarify, before you run the above statement there are no records in the table? And after you run the statement there are 2 records in the table? Have you verified that the record doesn't already exist e.g. `select * from dbo.Products`

Comment: Because what it looks looks like is that it worked for you once, and is then failing because you've hard coded the PK.

Comment: Just a side note: if you're inserting *numerical* values (like `Code` or `Price`) , you should **not** put those values into single quotes - that's unnecessary and causes T-SQL to have to do implicit type conversions ...

Comment: Have you fixed the issue? or else please share the table structure of your products table. Need to check why additional records are inserting

Comment: From what I understand is, there is a constraint in place to avoid duplication in the table, so the value you're trying to insert already exists in the table. I believe the answer @asmgx provided would resolve this issue...

Comment: The message "(2 rows affected)" implies that is more to the script than what you provided.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
IF Not EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM products WHERE code = '17881832980551')
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO products (code, P_Name, p_line, P_Collection, P_Colour,
                      P_Size, P_Price, active)
      VALUES ('17881832980551', 'Austin Record', 'T-Shirt', 'Classic', 'Athletic Heather',
        'S', '39.50', 'Y');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT 'Record already added'
END
```

Comment: Hey everyone, just seeing these now. A lot of great feedback and answers, much appreciated as I'm just starting out with SQL. The table was empty and I got the error message when I tried inserting my very first record.  I will look into this tonight after work and let you know if it worked!